# Can transformers be used to adjust capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, transformer, ac

It seems capacitors are subject to a "quality triangle", where we can only pick two out of three desirable traits:

- High voltage rating
- High capacitance
- Cheap

For example, a high-voltage high-capacitance capacitor is not likely to be cheap.

But, can we get around that by adding a step-up transformer with a cheap high-voltage low-capacitance capacitor on the secondary? Since

$$Z_{reflected} = \left(\frac{N_P}{N_S}\right)^2 Z_{secondary}$$

then that low-capacitance capacitor will reflect a much greater
$$ \frac{1}{j\omega C_{reflected}} = \left(\frac{N_P}{N_S}\right)^2\frac{1}{j\omega C} \Rightarrow C_{reflected} = \left(\frac{N_S}{N_P}\right)^2 C $$

Not sure if this is a common practice or not (or, if the cost of getting a properly-rated transformer would exceed that of just getting the more expensive, high-voltage, high-capacitance capacitor in the first place!)

Comment: Transformers tend to be more expensive than capacitors, I think. And also only work with AC.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? What purpose is the capacitor serving in your system?

Comment: You could also just use capacitors in series and parallel. Capacitors are more ideal components anyways.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The original motivation stemmed from a Quora question, about [high voltage capacitors with high capacitances](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-we-make-a-high-voltage-capacitor-with-very-high-voltage-capacitance-such-as-1-000-microfarad-or-more). This made me wonder if transformers could provide a simple workaround (around using otherwise expensive capacitors!). However, as DKNguyen pointed out, transformers are usually more expensive than capacitors, so this is not likely a viable workaround at all**

Comment: But a workaround for **what purpose**? What kind of circuit does it go into?

Comment: @DKNguyen That is a good point about series/parallel combinations! And that would work for DC applications too, not only AC. I would assume, though, in practice there may then be some cost or space tradeoff, instead? E.g., by combining multiple smaller/cheaper capacitors in series/parallel vs. using one single component?

Comment: @ManRow Perhaps, but you have to work with what you can get. Or just get it custom made which isn't as big a deal for really big high power projects.

Comment: There might be the possibility of a utility adding a transformer to a substation to put in a regional power factor correction capacitor bank rated below 10,000 volts where all of the lines in and out of the substation are higher voltage.

Comment: I actually found this to be an interesting question!  You might be interested to learn about [capacitance multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance_multiplier).

Comment: If you want a higher impedance, just use a lower value capacitor.

Comment: Cheap depends on how much your plant pays for excess VARs that could be corrected with PFC cap bank.. Perhaps beyond your cheap budget , but cost-effective, then cost depends on VAR not C or V per  se

Comment: _"high-voltage low-capacitance capacitor"_ - why you think the capacitor would be any cheaper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can Place the cap bank on the end of a transformer or even an auto transformer .Remember that the windings must handle the leading reactive capacitor current .So if your Cap bank is rated for say 100KVAr then 100KW is your required transformer rating .This at power frequencies looks expensive .I have not seen this done .I have seen tertiery windings on an existing transformer at 60Hz allowing for cheaper    low value high voltage film caps and have done this on a resonant mode powersupply at 150 KHz .I do not think that the economics will stack up for your job .

Comment: Prove your assumption.  What is cheaper for a 100:1 transformer  with 23kV to 230Vac? With requirement of 1kVAR capacitor @ 50 Hz . What is C,V ,$ value and cost difference with lightning clamp at 150% ?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "no."  A capacitor is, fundamentally, an energy storage device. The energy density (joules per liter) of a particular kind of capacitor (film, electrolytic, whatever) is roughly constant, whether a particular module is optimized for high voltage/low capacitance or for high capacitance/low voltage.  Transformers let us trade voltage for current, but the energy entering the low voltage side is still the same energy coming out the high voltage side.  So the same volume of capacitance (and thus the same approximate materials and cost) will be needed to do the same job, regardless of which side of the transformer the capacitor is installed on.

More broadly, you may be interested in the concept of a [Pareto Frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier).  The phenomenon you describe of being unable to optimize multiple qualities simultaneously, and thus having to make tradeoffs among them, is pretty much universal.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Pareto , a brilliant Swiss-Italian philosopher-engineer

Comment: But you should have emphasized energy density for each chemistry is  quite different for plastic vs e-caps . Only plastic and pref PU plastic is used on grid for PFC with self-healing properties.